# Can maven detect in advance runtime NoSuchMethodError caused by dependency conflict?

Tags: maven

Today, I ran into a runtime `NoSuchMethodError` caused by a guava dependency conflict:

One of my third-party dependencies, let's call it A, invokes `HostAndPort.getHost()`, which is defined in some guava version between (18.0, 23.6-jre]. A depends on guava:23.6-jre, so it's compiled without any problem. But I have another dependency, let's call it B, depend on guava:18.0, and unfortunately according to the rule of "nearest wins", maven choose guava:18.0.

Everything works fine while compiling and packaging, but the devil comes out in runtime, causing my program to crash, which is bad.

So, I wonder is there any way I can detect this kind of problem using tools like maven, so that I can fix them before launching my program?

Comment: maven-enforcer-plugin: convergence rule https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html

Comment: @khmarbaise I do have read some intro about enforcer, but it seams like enforcer is used to make detecting conflicts easier than simply using the `dependency` plugin. What I really want is to detect conflicts that will actually do harm to my program in runtime. enforcer output too much info, I just can't tell which I should fix.

Comment: Why do you use maven-dependency-plugin ? I don't understand your comment?